# Can't add elements to array

Tags: ruby

I am making a Yhatzee game, and Ive run into a very similar problem previously in the program that i managed to fix, but this one i can't seem to understand. Please forgive me if this is a noob question... I am a noob.

```
class  Yhatzee
  def dices
    @dice = Array.new(5){rand(1..6)}
  end

  def roll_dice
    puts dices
  end

  def dice_choice
    puts "do you want to keep any of the dices type 1-5 or 0 if you don't  want to keep any.?"

    keep_dice = gets.to_i

    if @dice[0] == keep_dice
      puts "#{keep_dice} keeping"
      @dice_log << keep_dice
    elsif @dice[1] == keep_dice
      puts "#{keep_dice} keeping"
      @dice_log << keep_dice
    elsif @dice[2] == keep_dice
      puts "#{keep_dice} keeping"
      @dice_log << keep_dice
    elsif @dice[3] == keep_dice
      puts "#{keep_dice}keeping"
      @dice_log << keep_dice
    elsif @dice[4] == keep_dice
      puts "#{keep_dice} keeping"
      @dice_log << keep_dice
    else
      puts "didn't work..."
    end
  end

  def dice_log
    @dice_log = Array.new(0)
    puts @dice_log
  end
end

x = Yhatzee.new
puts x.roll_dice
puts x.dice_choice
```

The error I'm getting is

```
`dice_choice': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Once you have it working, consider posting your code at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Will do Swoveland :) Thank's for referring me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're trying to use `@dice_log`, which is not yet defined. This results with your error of lack `<<` method for `nil`.

The simples thing you can do, is to `initialize` your `Yhatzee` with `@dice_log = Array.new(0)` like:

```
class  Yhatzee
  def initialize
    @dice_log = Array.new(0)
  end
  # ...
end
```

This will result that error `undefined method<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` disappear.

One more thing - remove `@dice_log = Array.new(0)` from your `dice_log` method. It will override whatever you have stored in your `@dice_log`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank's allot, i finally understood what I'm doing wrong now, I kept making that mistake in similar programs aswell having no idea what i was doing wrong.